# Alpha cut in fuzzy logic

Tags: set, fuzzy-logic

Can someone please explain in simple terms with an example what is aplha cut in fuzzy logic

I tried to understand on my own, by referring to this and I could only get the definition without any simple explanation with example

> The definition says something like
>
> Let µ ∈ F(X) and α ∈ [0, 1].
>
> Then the sets [µ]α = {x ∈ X | µ(x) ≥ α} , [µ]α = {x ∈ X | µ(x) > α}
>   are called the α-cut and strict α-cut of µ

Consider for example this fuzzy set

A = { 0/1 + 0.1/2 + 0.4/3 + 0.5/4 + 0.5/5 }

Can someone please try to explain with the above mentioned set

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It is the set of all `xs` where `mu(x)` is larger than `alpha`. In your example, assume `alpha` is 0.2. Then the alpha-cut is `{3,4,5}` because all of those `xs` have membership values greater than 0.2.